# Set data-attribute in html with jquery or javascript (on click) for a tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have the following **jQuery**, **CSS** and **HTML** lines:

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#main").data("ot", "test");
});
```

```css
#main {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 230px;
  text-align: center;
}
#button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" data-ot="tooltip content" data-ot-delay="0">Div Content (Tooltip Trigger)</div>
<div id="button">Change data-ot to test</div>
```

> OBS: The HTML attribute `data-ot` is where the tooltip gets the content from...

What I've been trying to do is change the attribute `data-ot` from it's initial to "**test**", as shown in the **jQuery** lines at the snippet.

I even tried using `$('#main').attr('data-ot', 'test');` and when I inspect the element in the page it seems to have changed, but the tooltip doesn't recognize the change. During my searches I read that `data()` and `attr()` shouldn't be used together for the same porpoise because there might be some conflicts, so I guess that explains why...

I'm really lost on this, any ideas?

Comment: Tooltip is not showing. Is activated by hover or click?

Comment: I did not place the tooltip codes in here because they require big scripts, and I figured the value being changed  could be seen by inspecting the element of the page

Comment: The correct way to change an HTML attr is to use $('#main').attr('data-ot', 'test');. If that change is not reflected in the tooltip it means the script you are using is not updating itself with the new attribute.

Comment: Can't add the tooltip files, they summed are too big and stackoverflow won't allow me to post it

Comment: Is it a plugin? Try to add a JSFiddle

Comment: yes its a plugin, I'm still trying in here with no success, thanks for your interest! here it goes: https://jsfiddle.net/gu8tu2ev/#&togetherjs=hfmOuPbQ2b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the plugin [documentation](http://www.opentip.org/documentation.html) you can set or change the attrbutes dynamically.

You can add this code:

```
var myOpentip = new Opentip($("#main"));
 myOpentip.setContent("First Content");

$("#button").click(function() {
  myOpentip.setContent("New content");
});
```

Also, you need to remove data-ot attribute from HTML.

JSFIddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kalimahapps/gu8tu2ev/1/

Comment: OMG I just woke up, been trying to fix that last night till 3:30 am, dude you rock seriously, I'm not experienced with javascript at all, thank you!

Comment: No problem. Maybe mentioning the plugin name in your question would have helped solve it faster. If you liked the answer maybe also vote it up :)

Comment: I can't right now due to my pontuation being so low, but I will in advance, promise. It was really helpful thank u so much again!

Answer (score 0):

tooltip value is set when document is built.so if you change it later it will not change the value.